# How should I count the number of occurrences of a character at the beginning of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, count, character

The best that I have been able to come up with is:

`strlen(preg_replace('/^([\\*]*)\s(.+)/',"$1",$line));`
^^That seems to give the length of the string.^^

edit: I think that I should clarify that the character that I am trying to find is '*'

Comment: because he said it in the duplicate(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441582/how-should-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-at-the-beginning-of-a). This 1 being the 1st had already 1 answer, so i flagged the other one.

Comment: I don't know how that happened. Perhaps I double-clicked or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preg_match allows an output parameter which is filled with the matches, thus you can simply take the strlen of the match for the pattern /^**/:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/^\**/", $string, $matches);
$result =  strlen($matches[0]) ;
```

...

```
"***Hello world!*" -> 3
"Hello world!" -> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little wonky but it might work--it counts the number of times the first character is repeated:

```
strlen($line) - strlen(ltrim($line, $line[0]));
```

If you just want to remove all the stars from beginning, then this is a little easier

```
strlen($line) - strlen(ltrim($line, '*'));
```